# Is it possible to compare Github users? Specifically their contributions?

Tags: github, statistics, compare

The company I work for uses GitHub extensively.  Is there is a way to compare my team's individual contributions to specific repositories on a weekly basis?

Apart from loading their individual GitHub profiles and comparing the statistics?

My team is growing at quite a rapid pace, and soon it will be difficult to find the time to manually compare them.  We also work in 4 different times zones thus it can be difficult to sync up with everyone effectively.

Comment: What metrics interest you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current main view which offer user activity comparison is the [Graphs view](https://github.com/blog/1093-introducing-the-new-github-graphs):

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f2af96058f156ef2b96a9e6e97b04775090b34ce/68747470733a2f2f6769746875622d696d616765732e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f626c6f672f323031322f6772617068732e636f6e7472696275746f72732e706e67]

(That and the [Pulse view](https://github.com/blog/1476-get-up-to-speed-with-pulse))